# How to access redux state after dispatch is finished fully?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am making a Create Operation. When the user clicks on onSubmit I am dispatching an action that creates a resource in the database and updates the store with the information that is returned from API call which contains information like status(indicating the status of operation) and error or message.

```
const initialState = {
   loading: true,
   status: false,
   error: false
}
```

Above is my initial state of redux store

```
const {loading,status} = useSelector(state=>state.newUser)
```

I am consuming the state using `useSelector`

```
const addUser = (values) => async (dispatch) => {
    const response = // Makes an API call return information
    dispatch({type:"ADD_USER",payload:response.data})
}

onSubmit = (values)=>{
    dispatch(addUser(values))
    .then(data=>{
        console.log(data)
    })
    if(!status){
       
    }
}
```

In the above onSubmit function when the user submits the form it dispatches an action and updates the store. Now based on the new state I want to update the UI. After dispatching I am checking whether the status of the operation is true or false. If false I want to display the error. The problem is after dispatching If I try to access `status` it gives me the `status` value from `initialState`. I want to execute the `if(!status)` after the states get updated.

Comment: Use `async/await` or `dispatch.then` as your `addUser` action returns a promise.

Comment: @morganney I update my code as you said. I used dispatch.then but when I tried to console.log the data I am getting undefined

Comment: You aren't returning the data in `addUser` though, you are updating the store.

Comment: If I return data why do I need to do this operation using redux? I could have just directly made an API call without redux and update the UI with the returned data. So does it make sense to use redux for this according to you?

Comment: Whether you want to use redux or not is up to you. The gist of your issue is that you are trying to read data without waiting for the asynchronous action to finish. Either return the data you want to read from `addUser` or read it in from the redux store, but whichever you choose do it after the asynchronous action, i.e. inside the  `then`.

On a side note, using redux to dispatch and store API calls is overkill and unnecessary. Do you really need this data in the store or is it only needed for one particular UI?

Answer (score 3):

In Redux everything is declarative, you can't wait for the async action like you do on promise calls. Instead you have to dispatch an action for failure and store the error in the reducer.

Your thunk should look like something below

```js
const addUser = (values) => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type:"ADDING_USER"}) // You can use this for showing some loading state
    const response = await getDataFromAPI(values);
    if(response.status === 200) {
        dispatch({type:"ADD_USER_SUCCEEDED", data: response.data});
    } else {
        dispatch({type:"ADD_USER_FAILED", error: "API Failed" });
    }  
}
```

And then in the component you have to listen for all the values that you need and write rendering logic declaratively based on the values.

```js
const {loading,status,error} = useSelector(state=>state.newUser)

if(error)
   return <p>API Call failed</p>;
else if(loading)
   return <p> Loading </p>;
else 
   return <p> Data saved </p>
```

If you need to trigger some logic based on it then you should be doing that in the thunk itself. By any chance if you need to trigger some function from the component when the value in the redux state changes, then you have to use `useEffect` and pass the value as dependency.

```js
useEffect(() => triggerFunction, [status]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Redux:

First of all, it's preferred to update your state to include only `status` and its value should be changed depending on the status of the request.
`status = 'idle'` or
`status = 'loading'` or
`status = 'succeded'` or
`status = 'failed'`

Second, in your `addUser function` you should use the `await` keyword before the request.

Third, you should check the status of the request if it failed or succeeded, this can be done inside the `addUser function` and dispatch one of the two actions one for failure and one for success to update the status, or you can do this after dispatching your action `({type:"ADD_USER",payload:response.data}) and check the response data in the reducer to update the status.

In the UI:

You need to access the data through `useSelector` as you did, but to take an action after a form submission which in turn will update the status in the store. You should do this in `useEffect` hook.

```
    useEffect(() => 
        if (status === 'failed') {
            // somecode
        } else if (status === 'succeeded') {
            // somecode
        }
    }, [status]);
```