# Race condition using redux toolkit dispatch

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

I am trying to conditionally navigate dependent on whether the logged in user has completed onboarding or not. In the below function the logic doesn't appear to await the dispatch for long enough (or at all) resulting in a race condition that causes `currentStudent.onboardingCompleted` to result in `undefined` and fire the wrong conditional navigation logic.

I'm wondering how better to structure things to be more stable?

```
const StudentLoginForm = () => {
  const [spellcastUsername, setSpellcastUsername] = useState('');
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const currentStudent = useSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.selectedStudent,
  );

  const handleSubmit = async (spellcastUsername: string) => {
    setIsLoading(true); // Start loading

    try {
      const isStudentAuthenticated = await api.dbAuthenticateStudent(
        spellcastUsername,
      );

      if (isStudentAuthenticated) {
        preloadPhonemeAudio();

        await dispatch(
          fetchStudentAndCreateSessionThunk(isStudentAuthenticated.id),
        );

        if (currentStudent?.onboardingCompleted === true) {
          navigate(`/cardgame/${isStudentAuthenticated.id}`);
        } else {
          navigate(`/profile/${isStudentAuthenticated.id}`);
        }
      } else {
        alert('No User');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error during form submission:', error);
      alert('An error occurred. Please try again.');
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };
[...]
```

Here is the thunk:

```
export const fetchStudentAndCreateSessionThunk = createAsyncThunk(
  'session/fetchAndCreate',
  async (studentId: string, { dispatch, getState }) => {
    await dispatch(fetchStudentByIdThunk(studentId));
    const state = getState() as RootState;
    const studentNode = state.selectedStudent;
    if (studentNode && studentNode.id) {
      dispatch(setSelectedStudent(studentNode));
      dispatch(createNewSessionThunk(studentNode.id));
    }
  },
);
```

I

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access redux state after dispatch is finished fully?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70037821/how-to-access-redux-state-after-dispatch-is-finished-fully)

Comment: I think that would answer his question too. Need to access that data from a useEffect. Otherwise, it is gonna access the current state, which can be null due to asynchronous behaviour of redux.